# Powershell find silverlight time elasped

Tags: silverlight, powershell, com, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to use PowerShell to find the total time elapsed for a Silverlight web application (IE10) to load. Since this is a Silverlight app, I wished to find the time elapsed AFTER Silverlight loads, not just when the web page loads. I've tried the following but Silverlight always crashes.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
while($ie.busy){}#wait for browser to load
$time = measure-command -expression{
                $ie.navigate('http://www.mysilverlightapp.com')
                while($ie.readyState -ne 4){}
}
write-host "$($time.totalseconds)"
```

Please help me on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Probably put `start-sleep 1` in your waiting loops?

Comment: Thanks, that helped stopping Silverlight from crashing!  $ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
while($ie.busy){}#wait for browser to load
$time = measure-command -expression{
                $ie.navigate('http://www.mysilverlightapp.com')
                while($ie.readyState -ne 4){start-sleep 1; break; }
}
write-host "$($time.totalseconds)"

but it stops when the browser loads. Im trying to get it to stop when silverlight loads.